# Typing into android-studio over X Forwarding sends text into the console instead

Tags: xforwarding, user-input

I am running `android-studio` from the command line on another machine on my home network.  I am connecting to that machine using:

```
ssh -C -X machine-name.local
```

Keypresses do not seem to be registered by the application.  No text is entered into the window.  Keyboard shortcuts don't work.

Mouse input is fine.  I can click on a menu or whatever and the application updates within a quarter second.

I have tried to enter text into `gvim` and `xterm` and this works just fine.  I tried other applications and they seemed to work fine.  It's just `android-studio`.